# Measuring disk I/O usage of a program

Tags: io, time, measure

`time` is a brilliant command if you want to figure out how much CPU time a given command takes.

I am looking for something similar that can measure the disk I/O of the program and any children. Preferably it should distinguish between I/O that was cached (and thus did not cause the disk to spin) and I/O that was not cached.

So I would like to do:

```
iomeassure my_program my_args
```

and get output similar to:

```
Cached read: 10233303 Bytes
Cached write: 33303 Bytes  # This was probably a tmp file that was erased before making it to the disk
Non-cached read: 200002020 Bytes
Non-cached write: 202020 Bytes
```

I have looked at `vmstat`, `iostat`, and `sar`, but none of these are looking at a single process. Instead they look at the whole system.

I have looked at `iotop`, but that only gives me a view this instant.

--- edit ---

snap's answer seems close.

'File system inputs:' is the non-cached reads in 512-byte blocks.

'File system outputs:' is the cached writes in 512-byte blocks.

You can force the cache empty with:

```
sync ; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches >/dev/null
```

I tested with:

```
 seq 10000000 > seq
 /usr/bin/time -v bash -c 'perl -e "open(G,\">f\"); print G <>;close G; unlink \"f\";" seq'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not specify which operating system you use.

### Linux

Instead of using `time foo` which is (usually) a shell built-in you could try the external command `/usr/bin/time foo`. It gives some additional information such as number of file system inputs and outputs (but no information about cache hits or byte amounts). See [`man time`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) and [`man getrusage`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) for further instructions.

Note that this feature requires Linux kernel version 2.6.22 or newer.

### FreeBSD

Use `/usr/bin/time -l foo`. It gives the number of inputs and outputs. See [`man time`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=time&sektion=1) and [`man getrusage`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getrusage&sektion=2) for further instructions.